# SQL Agent Environment Variables not usable from Referenced Environment

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-agent-job, ssis-2017

I am trying to set up a SQL Agent Job in SQL Server 14.0.3436.1 (2017), using the SSIS Catalog as a source for an SSIS Package.

When I add the package, I can choose the environments I have set up, but for some reason I do not get presented with the radio button to "Use Environment Variable" for the package variables, so I can only hard code the values.

Any ideas what is going on here? All my Googling just tells me how to set up environments and variables, or how to access them with Python - I haven't found any references to a known bug or anything like that.

I have attached a video to demonstrate what I mean (although what I am showing is the *absence* of a button!)

[image: Problem - No Environment Available]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you want to map an environment variable  to a project/package parameter - you can do it from the project configuration menu (SSMS/Integration Services Catalog/SSISDB//Projects and select "configure" from the right click menu)

When creating a SSIS step in SQL Agent Job you can select the environment that should be used for populating package/project parameters or you can overwrite the value with a static text

Here is a detailed description with screenshots:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4810/setup-environment-variables-in-sql-server-integration-services/

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I have already associated the job with an environment, which contains the requisite variables, hence I am able to select the environment as per the video above. Is there some way that I could select the environment but not have the variables populate, that you know of (I believe the names match and so on, but that should only matter for the automatic selection - I can't even manually select a variable from the chosen environment...)

Comment: Assigning the job to the environment is one thing, but you still need to assign a environment variable to each project/package parameter. Try to right click on the project in Integration Services Catalogs, select "configure" - click on the three dots next to any parameter and tell me if you can see "Use environment variable" option, If you do , but it is not you were looking for then I most likely did not understand your question :)